# Overpass does not find all cinemas - Overpass API documentation

Tags: r, openstreetmap, overpass-api

In the openstreetmap [overpass API-documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Relative_to_other_elements_.28around.29) there is the following example:

```
area[name="Bonn"];
node(area)[highway=bus_stop];
node(around:100)[amenity=cinema];
out;
```

Why does this query does not give the Kinopolis (in Bonn Bad Godesberg) as a result? See here: http://rpubs.com/hrbrmstr/overpass for the results from the API. The following two images illustrate that it really is <100m by foot.

[image]
Unfortunately i wasnt able to show it graphically on the openstreetmap... I dont know how to get the busstop as startingpoint of a route in the web interface...
Here is the Google-Maps version.
[image]

Comment: it cld just be a prblm with the overpass pkg. i may have time tomorrow to take a look.

Comment: @hrbrmstr that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Shall i open a ticket?

Comment: np. i'll just ref this one in an issue

Comment: Is it because there is no node for that cinema, just a way?

Comment: @Spacedman how do i check that?

Comment: @Floo0 try running some queries on http://overpass-turbo.eu/ (as per the answer below!)

Comment: It perfectly ok to have cinema POI mapped as way in OpenStreetMap, POIs don't have to be a node to start with. You just need to take this into account for your query as well, otherwise you will not get all results - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've asked for cinema nodes only in your example query, the result will not include way 42473787. Here's how your query should look like to return ways with `amenity=cinema` instead:

```c
area[name="Bonn"];
node(area)[highway=bus_stop];
way(around:100)[amenity=cinema];
(._;>;);
out meta;
```

To get both nodes and ways in one query, simply use a union:

```c
area[name="Bonn"];
node(area)[highway=bus_stop]->.bus_stops;
( 
  way(around.bus_stops:100)[amenity=cinema];
  node(around.bus_stops:100)[amenity=cinema];
);
(._;>;);
out meta;
```

Try it in [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/kWh)!

[image]

Comment: understood from a programming/data-storage point of view: `node` != `way`. From a user-perspective: do i always have to think about the data-storage of openstreetmap? How can i query anything (`node`, `way`, `rel`, etc.) around bus stops? Kind of `*(around.bus_stops:100)[amenity=cinema]`. And the second thing: Are all bus-stops nodes? If i understand the query correctly `node(area)[highway=bus_stop]` will only return `nodes`. Can there be bus_stops of type `way` as well? To generalize this: How to get all busstops, e.g. `*(area)[highway=bus_stop]`

Comment: Yes, at this time you need to mention every single type explicitly in your query. There's an enhancement request out there on this topic, but it hasn't been implemented yet. https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/150 - there are also 3 bus_stops modeled as way - you can assign them to the `.bus_stops` input set via a union as well.